# How can I disable Wi-Fi settings redirection and display my website when accessing my Vodafone router via noip DDNS?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ddns, self-hosting

I have connected my Vodafone router to noip ddns provider and want to host a website on it. But when I type the domain name I got redirected to my wifi settings page. I want to turn this off and display my website instead. How can i do this?

Comment: What model is your router? Is your site actually installed on the router, or do you have a computer device connected to the router the site is actually running on?

Comment: It's the Vodafone Gigabox router. Website is running on the computer which is connected to the router

Answer (score 0):

This is a LOT more complex then it sounds (especially if we assume oyu are using IPV4)

If the website is running on a computer on your LAN, ddns will not help you find your website in the local network.  You will need to do something to resolve the domain name locally - possibly editing the hosts file, or conceivably using another mechanism in the router or network.

Assuming a typical setup for a small business/home - each of the computers on your LAN will have what is called an RFC1918 address - basically an address which is only used in your LAN.   Your router will translate these internal addresses and share them behind a single IP address which it shares with the world.    (It is possible that there is another set of sharing going on at the router called Carrier grade NAT  (CGN), but that will be provider dependent).

If you are using CGN, you are probably out-of-luck if you want this page to be visible outside your network.   If you have a valid IP address assigned to your router, you will need to port forward the appropriate ports in your router back to your PC's address.

Even if you can set up port forwarding, this will usually only work from outside your network unless your router has some advanced functionality not common in home routers called hairpin NAT.